# Visio 2013 Preview Drawing Control on a Windows Forms Application Crashes

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, visio

Visual Studio 2012 crashes when open a form that contains a Visio 2013 Preview Drawing control. (Microsoft Visio 15.0 Drawing Control - Com Component).

Steps to reproduce this issue.

1. Open Visual Studio 2012
2. Create a new Windows Forms Application (C#)
3. Add COM Component Microsoft Visio 15.0 Drawing control to toolbox.
4. Place Visio Drawing Control on Form2.cs[Design].
5. Save all files, project and solution.
6. Close Form1.cs [Design] in the Visual Studio 2012 IDE.
7. Double click Form1.cs in the Solution explorer to edit form [Design] view.
8. Visual Studio Application Crashes at this point.

Is this a known bug in Visio 2013 Preview.

Using the Visio 2013 Drawing Control in VB6 applications also produces a similar result with &H80004005 (-2147467259) error message shown.

Our product makes use of the Visio 2013 control in a VB6 application. It is also an issue in Visual Studio 2012.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a known bug: See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766229/visio-2013-preview-drawing-control-on-a-windows-forms-application-crashes

The best workaround I could come up with so far was to instantiate the drawing control in code only. In other words. Don't drag it onto your form (etc.) from the toolbox in the IDE but only create and instantiate the control from within the code. That way the control does not appear in the GUI form editor and it will not freeze your Visual Studio instance.

If you are not sure how to do that you can always drag it temporarily to your form and lift the relevant code for the control from your FormName.Designer.cs (or .vb) file.

Mind you my experience is with VS2012 only. I am not sure if you can even use the control in VB6 (don't have it installed to test).

Comment: Yeah thats my post on connect.microsoft.com. Thanks for the work around in VS2012. I have not tried it yet. Going to wait until the RC and see if it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Option Explicit

Private WithEvents moo As Visocxctl.DrawingControl

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set moo = Form1.Controls.Add("VisOcx.DrawingControl.1", "VisioRuntime")
    moo.Left = 0
    moo.Top = 0
    moo.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:
[Visio Drawing Control Fails in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095726/visio-drawing-control-fails-in-visual-studio-2012).
Replace Office14 with Office15 for Visio 2013. I could successfully drop the control in design-time and run a sample windows form application. This is a known bug in VS2012 when working with any version of Visio drawing control.